# Problem writing serial data from Arduino to a text file on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am trying print data from serial port to a text file, but text file won't open and gives the error `invalid byte sequence in conversion input.`

here is the relevant part of the code

```
file = open('file name', 'a')
read_serial = ser.readline()
file.write(read_serial)
file.close()
```

I'm using a Pi Zero W. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: so it fails at `open` or at `write`?

Comment: Can you open the file with VIM? Perhaps the issue is with the encoding of the file.